# Django tutorial login, delete data on user logging out

Tags: django, session, multi-tenant

I am preparing a multitenant website on Django using tenant-id for identification (and not schema). Now, for tutorial, I would want to have a webpage with sample login and password (like Django CMS does). However, I don't want to store user data from that login/password combination, so that the data would be availabale for each session and as soon as the user logs out, the data deletes. Is there any application/packages that could help me with this? Otherwise, how can I do this?

Comment: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this request.

Comment: Thnxxx GhostCat!! Hope that works out